# Create a Header in Bootstrap 4 with correctly aligned logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a header in bootstrap 4 like this:
[image: Header with Logo on the left side that is pulled to the bottom of the h1 element. It contains the text Some text in big letters with smaller letters saying "The new way of doing text-research"]
I'm facing several problems with this approach. Firstly the logo is not properly centered to the middle. I've tried several methods to avoid this including align=middle, margin on the bottom (which adds more space on the bottom than the space that's already on top-side) and the grid-system with col-1 and col-9. The last one creates to much space between the logo and the heading.

The image includes the version which contains the image in the HTML h1 element. Here is the source to create the logo:

```html
<h1 class="display-4 bg-primary text-light">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64" width=64 height=64 />Some text 
<small class="text-white-50">
The new way of doing text-research</small></h1>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Bootstrap examples with an included logo are very rare. Maybe it has a reason...

**Additional information**

- The small text shouldn't be centered.
- I want to achieve this with **bootstrap utilities only**.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: @JulianSilvestri I said, I want to achieve this with bootstrap utilities only.

Comment: Is that not bootstrap ? Im confused how that will be achieved without using CSS

Comment: please show a seperate example of what you mean by bootstrap utilities only

Comment: @Julian Silvestri no custom css

Comment: Ok, check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for all items. Don't put the image and  text inside the h1.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center/* vertical alignment */
}

small {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64" width=64 height=64 />
  <h1 class="display-4 bg-primary text-light">Some text<small class="text-white-50">The new way of doing text-research</small></h1>

</div>
```

Comment: But this causes the small text to also be centered. I don't want to center the small text.

Comment: So there is no way, to do this with bootstrap only?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no html posted i am going to assume you have bootsrap basics in place:

Assuming you have something like this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 header">
            <span>
               <h1 class="display-4 bg-primary text-light">
                 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64" width=64 height=64/>
                 some text
                <small>The new way of doing text-research</small>
              </h1>
            </span>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: REMOVED CUSTOM CSS

PLease note that having the html in this way is not recommended. 
But if you are insistent that you not use any custom css this solution should solve the problem.

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Check updated code pen https://codepen.io/Jsilvestri/pen/vzzJRy